# How to show notifications when application is closed

Tags: flutter, websocket, push-notification, notifications

I am new to flutter development.

My application requires to display notifications to user.

This flutter application connect to a websocket and show notifications when the application is open.

I want to show notifications when the mobile app when it is closed.
I have seen other applications do this.

I have seen several push notifications plugins in https://pub.dev/

Do I have to use push notification plugin ?

or

Is there an another mechanism to do something like this?

Can someone provide some direction on how to proceed with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase cloud message (fcm) for your use case, each device have a unique token, you can trigger this fcm using a url and you can pass this token, so the only device that receive this notification is the wanted device. I think in your case since the application is closed the backend need to trigger this function.

If you want some steps to follow

- connect your app to firebase
- check fcm and try to send messages to all users from their cloud messaging tab in the website (try to send while app is fully closed, while app is running, and while app is in the background)
- get the device token and try to send the message from the UI to only one user.
- now try to trigger it from the URL

**Note** For IOS you need the app to be released to the store in order to see the notifications and you can't see these notifications in the IOS simulator.

Comment: thank you for your answer. In my app I already have the web sockets system to send messages. The problem is it is not working when the application is closed.  May I know whether there is a way to capture these socket messages? 
Do I need to write a plugin to do this?

Comment: I don't think its possible to receive data in web socket while the app is closed, especially for IOS, however fcm will work even if the app is closed.

Comment: i understand. I am new to mobile application development. Is there a way to run a service while the application is closed. I am wondering how other applications do it? Are they all using firebase cloud messing?

Comment: I am not an expert, but there are multiple cloud messaging libraries that can be used, I am only familiar with firebase, what kind of services do you mean that run while application is closed ?

Comment: I am thinking of running a custom service that connect to our websocket and get the messages. I am not really sure what is the correct approach in such cases. I am trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible to do while the app is closed. The only way to send messages while the app is closed is using cloud messaging